# MySQL query that selects all users that have more than one entry per day

Tags: mysql, database

I want to get all the USER_ID for users who have posted more than one thing per day,

I tried originally tried this

```
    SELECT USER_ID, count(DISTINCT cast(POSTING_DATE as DATE))
    AS NUM_DAYS_OF_DUPLICATES FROM POSTING_TABLE
    WHERE USER_ID IN
        (SELECT USER_ID FROM POSTING_TABLE
        GROUP BY CAST(POSTING_DATE AS DATE) HAVING count(*) >= 2)
    GROUP BY USER_ID ORDER BY NUM_DAYS_OF_DUPLICATES DESC;
```

Then this works for a specific USER_ID

```
    SELECT USER_ID FROM POSTING_TABLE WHERE USER_ID = 30 
    GROUP BY cast(POSTING_DATE AS DATE) 
    HAVING count(cast(POSTING_DATE AS DATE)) > 1
```

The above gives me the correct result, however when I run the query on the entire table without specifying a USER_ID it does not.

eg.,

table structure USER_ID, POSTING_DATE ...

```
    USER_ID POSTING_DATE
    1       10-10-13
    1       10-10-13
    1       10-12-13
    1       10-12-13
    2       10-10-13
    2       10-10-13
    3       10-10-13
    4       10-12-13
```

Where the result would give me

```
    USER_ID  NUM_DAYS_WITH_MORE_THAN_ONE_POSTING
    1        2
    2        1
    3        0
    4        0
```

Also if we can omit the 0's

Comment: @Travesty3 Somebody will give the answer to fetch some points :)

Comment: Add distinct to count and group by USER_ID instead of POSTING_DATE

Comment: You will probably have the answer by now ... since, as other comments implied, this is a very basic question. Instead of just copying the answer though, you should take some time investigating the [`GROUP BY` clause](http://beginner-sql-tutorial.com/sql-group-by-clause.htm) and the [`COUNT() aggregate function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count)

Comment: Adding distinct gives me all the different days posted, I am looking to count all of times the same date is repeated PER USER_ID

Comment: The OP added more detail, so I would take back my close vote if I could. However, even though it looks like a simple "How do I use `GROUP BY`" question, it's actually not that basic. I realized that after trying to come up with a solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution

```
select x.user_id, count(x.num_days)
from
(
select USER_ID, COUNT(USER_ID) AS NUM_DAYS
from data1 
group by user_id, posting_date
having count(user_id) > 1
) x
group by 1
```

### [Working SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1d314/6/0)

(I used a varchar for date for simplicity but it should work fine with `date` too. You can check with your own database)

Comment: +1, I came up with a similar query, but was trying to figure out a way to do it without the sub-select. Couldn't come up with anything.